# ¿Por qué esta consulta UPDATE no funciona en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el siguiente archivo para actualizar unos registros que no tienen ningun valor en su campo "totaldemerito":

El problema a pesar de que dice "actualizado" y la query no da error, NO PASA NADA.

El sistema deberia:

- Si tiene 0 en total_circunstancias1 asignar $demeritobase a $total_sancion
- Si tiene 0 en total_circunstancias2 asignar $demeritobase a $total_sancion
- Si tiene 0 en total_circunstancias1 y total_circunstancias2 asignar $demeritobase a $total-sancion

He aquí mi código:

```
<html>
<head>
<title> Calculador de Demerito </title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"> Calculador </h1>
<table border="1" style="float: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
<tr>
<td>Fecha de Inicio</td>
<td>Id Sancion</td>
<td>Grado</td>
<td>Tipo Sancion</td>
<td>Dias</td>
<td>Total demerito sin circunstancias</td>
<td>Atenuantes</td>
<td>Agravantes</td>
<td>Total Circunstancias Atenuantes</td>
<td>Total Circunstancias Agravantes</td>
<td>Total demerito con circunstancias</td>
<td>Estadp</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<?php
//init_set('max_execution_time',2000);
$query = "SELECT id_sancionado,cgrado, tipo_sancion,dias,c_agravante,c_atenuante,fecha_inicio FROM sancionados  WHERE totaldemerito=0 AND fecha_actual>=2017-03-01 ORDER BY id_sancionado";
$resultado = mysql_query($query) OR DIE("La consulta $query fallo" . mysql_error());

while ($registros = mysql_fetch_array($resultado)) //SI EXISTEN REGISTROS
    {

    $id=$registro["id_sancionado"];
    $grado = $registros["cgrado"];
    $tipo_sancion = $registros["tipo_sancion"];
    $dias = $registros["dias"];

        $query2 = "SELECT * from pmidemerim where cgrado=$grado";
    $resultado2 = mysql_query($query2) OR DIE("La consulta $query2 fallo" . mysql_error());
    $registros2 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado2);

    if ($tipo_sancion == 1)
        {
        $tipo_medida = $registros2["qpamonesta"];
        $tipo_sancion_desc = "AMONESTACION: " . $tipo_medida;
        $demeritobase = $tipo_medida;
        }

    if ($tipo_sancion == 2)
        {
        $tipo_medida = $registros2["qparr_simple"];
        $tipo_sancion_desc = "SIMPLE: " . $tipo_medida;
        $demeritobase = $dias * $tipo_medida;
        }

    if ($tipo_sancion == 3)
        {
        $tipo_medida = $registros2["qparre_severo"];
        $tipo_sancion_desc = "SEVERO: " . $tipo_medida;
        $demeritobase = $dias * $tipo_medida;
        }

echo "<td>" . $registros["id_sancionado"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $tipo_sancion_desc . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $registros["dias"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $demeritobase . "</td>";

    $atenuantes=$registros["c_atenuante"];
    echo "<td>" . $atenuantes ."</td>";

    $agravantes=$registros["c_agravante"];
    echo "<td>" . $agravantes . "</td>";

    $atenuantes_explode = explode("-", $atenuantes);
    $cantidad_atenuantes= count($atenuantes_explode);
    $total_circunstancias1=0;
    echo "total-atenuantes".$cantidad_atenuantes;

    $agravantes_explode = explode("-", $agravantes);
    $cantidad_agravantes= count($agravantes_explode);
    $total_circunstancias2=0;
    echo "total-agravantes".$cantidad_agravantes;

for ($i=0; $i<$cantidad_atenuantes;$i++){
        $atenuante_seleccionado=$atenuantes_explode[$i]*1;
        echo "atenuante seleccionado".$atenuante_seleccionado;
        $query3 = "SELECT * from causas_nuevas2 where c_articulo=40 and c_aparte='$atenuante_seleccionado'"; 
        $resultado3 = mysql_query($query3) OR DIE("La consulta $query3 fallo" . mysql_error());

        if($registros3 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado3)){
        $valor_atenuante=$registros3["valor"];
        $total_circunstancias1=$total_circunstancias1+$valor_atenuante;
    }
}


for ($i=0; $i<$cantidad_agravantes;$i++){
        $agravante_seleccionado=$agravantes_explode[$i]*1;
        $query4 = "SELECT * from causas_nuevas2 where c_articulo=41 and c_aparte='$agravante_seleccionado'"; 
        $resultado4 = mysql_query($query4) OR DIE("La consulta $query3 fallo" . mysql_error());

        if($registros4 = mysql_fetch_array($resultado4)){
        $valor_agravante=$registros4["valor"];
        $total_circunstancias2=$total_circunstancias2+$valor_agravante;
    }
}

if ($total_circunstancias1>0){
    $total_sancion=$demeritobase-($demeritobase*$total_circunstancias1);
    if($total_sancion>=100){
        $total_sancion=100;
    }
}

if ($total_circunstancias2>0){
    $total_sancion=$demeritobase+($demeritobase*$total_circunstancias2);
    if($total_sancion>=100){
        $total_sancion=100;
    }
}

if ($total_circunstancias1==0 && $total_circunstancias2==0){
    $total_sancion=$demeritobase;
    if($total_sancion>=100){
        $total_sancion=100;
    }
}





$queryx = "UPDATE sancionados SET totaldemerito = '$total_sancion' WHERE id_sancionado = '$id'";
$resultadox = mysql_query($queryx) OR DIE("La consulta $queryx fallo" . mysql_error());
    echo "<td>Total demeritobse".$demeritobase."</td>";
       echo "<td>total circunstancias 1=" . $total_circunstancias1 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>total circunstancias 2=" . $total_circunstancias2 . "</td>";
    echo "<td>total sancion=" . $registros["id_sancionados"] . "</td>";


    echo "</tr>";
}


?>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ohhhh no. La extensión `mysql_.*` es obsoleta, recomiendo que no pierdas tiempo tratando de corregir código basado en dicha función. Porque 1º puedes ser víctima de una Inyección SQL y 2º porque cuando pases a PHP 7 ese código no funcionará. Si mal no recuerdo, creo que ya te lo había advertido. Saludos.

Comment: Jejeje ya corregi eso en mis futuros proyectos :), es un sistema de un amigo

Comment: Responde a tu propia pregunta y marcala como respondida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Había varios errores en la consulta:

**1)** Para establecer comparaciones de fecha, esta debe estar entre comillas:

- incorrecto: `fecha_actual>=2017-03-01`
- correcto: `fecha_actual>='2017-03-01'`

**2)** La variable $id no se estaba obteniendo, ya que tenía un error tipográfico:

- incorrecto: `$id=$registro["id_sancionado"];`
- correcto: `$id=$registros["id_sancionado"];`

No me percataba del error porque estaba obteniendo bien el id de esta forma:

```
$registros["id_sancionado"];
```

**3)** El total demérito que queria calcular no debía ir entre comillas, las quité y empezo a mostrar el valor:

```
totaldemerito = $total_sancion
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta esto :

```
"UPDATE sancionados SET totaldemerito = ".$total_sancion." WHERE id_sancionado = ".$id;
```

Comment: muestra el error que te sale y ponla como imagen